# MVC3 with Razor throws Method not found: 'System.Object System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ViewModel()'

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Fresh IIS7.5 installation on Win Server 2008 R2.

Installed MVC3 etc. via Web Platform Installer.

Made a basic MVC3 application locally. Just "new project" without anything to it.
Made an application on the IIS to host the application. AppPool set to .Net4.

When I run the application locally I get this:

> Blockquote
>
> Method not found: 'System.Object
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ViewModel()'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method
>   not found: 'System.Object
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ViewModel()'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: Method not
>   found: 'System.Object
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ViewModel()'.]
>   MinTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index()
>   in C:\Projects\MinTest\MinTest\Controllers\HomeController.cs:17
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase
>   , Object[] ) +79
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +264
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>   +129    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   +784922    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +784976    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +159    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +335
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5()
>   +62    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   +20    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d()
>   +54    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +453    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +371

I'm lost!

t.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are actually loading MVC 3 in IIS. Sounds like you're getting MVC 2 instead. Double-check your MVC 3 installation on the server. Also examine the `bindingRedirect` in Web.Config.

Comment: you're right! Sort of.. The production environment was MVC3, but my development machine was on MVC3 RC.. :)